# Frequency range for set of all discrete-time sinusoids

Tags: discrete-signals, theory

Consider discrete time sinusoids of the form $$x[n] = \cos(\omega n) \ ,$$ where $n$ is an integer. What frequency range of $\omega$ would constitute all the possible sinusoids? I'm thinking that $0\leq\omega<\pi$ would suffice, but my teacher tells me it's $-\pi\leq\omega<\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming $\omega$ is real, if the form of $x[n]$ is how you've defined it above, your thinking is correct.  doesn't matter if it's $+\omega$ or $-\omega$, the sinusoid behaves exactly the same.  if instead, the sinusoid had form

$$ x[n] = e^{j \omega n}  \ ,$$

then your teacher would be correct.

Comment: Thanks robert bristow-johnson. If we changed $\cos$ to $\sin$, does there exist a $\pi$ range of $\omega$ such that would constitute all the sinusoids? $0\leq\omega<\pi$ wouldn't work for $\sin$, because $\sin(-\pi/2 n)$ is not included.

Comment: it's a polarity change.  you would have generality back again if your question was posed as $$ x[n] = A \sin(\omega n) $$ or  $$ x[n] = A \cos(\omega n) $$ but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You're saying that $\sin(-\pi/2 n)$ is just a sign change from $\sin(\pi/2 n)$? If you don't mind me asking - why doesn't the sign matter?

Comment: it might.  but it's basically the same as a scaler.  or it can be viewed as just a delay of 1/2 cycle.